# getActionView() of Item Drawer return null

Tags: android

I have problem with item drawer. I want to get view of item drawer, but it's return null.
this is my menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_biodata"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Biodata" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_kantor_dinas"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Kantor Dinas" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_aktivitas"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Aktivitas" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

and this is try getview :

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu item = navigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem biodata = item.getItem(0);
v_biodata  = biodata.getActionView();
```

v_biodata  is null. So how to fix it ? thanks... sorri for my English.

Comment: what your are trying to do???

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar i  try https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide  for itemmenu drawer

Comment: its ok but how TourGuide and biodata.getActionView() related, i think you are trying to call TourGuide screen(activity/fragment) on click of NavigationView item Biodata??

Comment: no, i call tour guide when drawer is opened, and tour guide is focus at each item menu drawer..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the views of navigation drawer items using this snippet.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
View view = navigationView.getTouchables().get(3); //Pass index to get function to get your desired item view.
```